# ImportError with keras.preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

I am following a [image classification tutorial at Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#predict_on_new_data). On running the following code-

```
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

sunflower_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/592px-Red_sunflower.jpg"
sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Red_sunflower', origin=sunflower_url)
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(sunflower_path, target_size=(180, 180))
```

I receive the following error at the last line.

```
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

How can I fix the above issue?

Kindly note that I have pillow installed on my conda working environment (python=3.8, Tensorflow=2.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you don't have `pillow` installed on your machine.
If you're using conda, then you have to do

```
conda install pillow
```

If you're not using conda, then I would just try

```
pip install pillow
```

**Edit 1**: In case you have PIL installed in a conda env already, then try

```
conda uninstall PIL
conda install Pillow
```

**Edit 2**: In case you may have an older version of Pillow installed that does not work with the version of TensorFlow/Keras installed in your env, reinstalling Pillow might help.

Comment: @ pkj I updated my answer. Sometimes PIL could be acting weird so I'd uninstall it and do `conda install Pillow`. A good place to look at is [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: `import PIL` in my code is redundant, it is there to represent that PIL could be loaded, but I will reinstall pillow

Comment: @pkj `keras.preprocessing.image.load_img` raises `ImportError` if `PIL` is not available. I'd first uninstall PIL and install only Pillow to see if that error does not show up again.

Comment: `PIL ` was not installed on my env, but surprisingy reinstalling `pillow` har solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: please also include in your answer "reinstalling `pillow` may help"